# Tabbed scope bar like Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Are there any open source implementations of a tabbed scope bar like Xcode 4 has? I have seen [MGScopeBar](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/28/mgscopebar/), but it doesn't have the icon tab appearance I'm looking for. It uses recessed buttons, while Xcode's tabs have a full-height highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at

**[DMTabBar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmtabbar)**:
*DMTabBar is a simple segmented control / bar that mimics the XCode 4 Inspector segmented control.*

[image]

[CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) also provides heaps of other great Open Source Cocoa controls.

Comment: Great, that looks like just what I need. There's a comment on the page that the code doesn't seem to have been pushed yet, but it's outdated. The code's all there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [DOTabbar](https://github.com/stel/DOTabbar) and create your custom tabbar item cell.

Comment: That looks like it would be more work, since it seems designed to imitate a regular toolbar.